# failed to import blender JSON in three.js

Tags: typescript, three.js, blender

I am new to blender and three.js. At the moment I am having some problem importing the JSON file exported from blender into three.js. However, the imported model is not appearing in the browser and I can't even find the problem.

This is the code in typescript.

```
  initWebGL() {

    // Setting up the three major needs
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(1, 2, 5);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor('rgb(120, 120, 120)');
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);    
    let loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('./assets/modulr.json', function (geometry, materials) {
      var material = materials[0];
      var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(object);
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}
```

When I console.log(scene), the object appears in the Console, but it is not appearing in the browser.Can someone please tell me which part of the code have I done wrongly.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reducing the problem and making a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This might help you to find the problem yourself, or at least identify the specific bit of code that is causing the problem, which will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have shortened the code to only the specific bit that is causing the problem.The object I added to the scene is not appearing in the browsers.